# Where are the buttons?

Tags: bug, review, design

While reviewing First Posts and Late Answers in Gaming Stack Exchange, I found out an interesting bug that only shows two of the three buttons at a time. At first it shows "No Action Needed" and "Skip" if I don't do anything:

[image]

Thus I can't see the "I'm Done" button. When I do the appropriate action for the answer, "I'm Done" appears but "No Action Needed" disappears:

[image]

Can we fix this bug? I remember that the button you can't choose greys out and becomes unclickable while the button you are "supposed" to choose becomes clickable and back to its regular color, not disappearing and appearing.

Comment: I agree, the previous behavior was more intuitive.